# Infopath File Submitted to Sharepoint Library is uneditabe?

Tags: infopath

I have a published infopath file on our Sharepoint 2010 and after someone fills it out and submits it we are unable to then edit it with more detail. Yet we have other Infopath forms where this is an option!?